# Combining $this in jQuery/Javascript with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two different bodies of code that basically do the work of checking whether or not a user's click is equal to a correct answer, and executing code depending on equality.

```
$(".practice-quiz-answer-choice").on("click",
function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.text() === $(".correct-choice").text()) {
    clickSpark.setParticleImagePath('../../correct-answer-checkmark.png');
    clickSpark.setParticleCount(50);
    clickSpark.setParticleSize(20);
    clickSpark.setParticleSpeed(12);
        clickSpark.fireParticles($(this));
        toggleNav();

    $this.css({
        backgroundColor: '#78e08f',
        transition: ".25s all"
    });

    $(".practice-quiz-answer-choice").not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).css({
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          transition: ".25s all"
      });
    });
  }
  else {
    $this.css({
        backgroundColor: '#e55039',
        transition: ".25s all"
    });
  }
});
```

And my other AJAX code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.answer").on( "click", function( event ) {
var current_answer = $(this);
var question_id = '<%= mcq.id %>';
var current_user = "<%= current_user.id %>";

$.ajax({
url: "/verify_user_selected_answer",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: {user_id: current_user, question: question_id, answer: current_answer.text()},
success: function(response){
$("#display_result").text(response["result"]);
}
});
});
});
```

I have tried to combine the two, so that it shows the visual changes and sends a POST via Ajax, but it just does not work. How can I do this?

EDIT: Here's what I meant by combining the code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.answer").on( "click", function( event ) {
var current_answer = $(this);
var question_id = '<%= mcq.id %>';
var current_user = "<%= current_user.id %>";

var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.text() === $(".correct-choice").text()) {
    clickSpark.setParticleImagePath('../../correct-answer-checkmark.png');
    clickSpark.setParticleCount(50);
    clickSpark.setParticleSize(20);
    clickSpark.setParticleSpeed(12);
        clickSpark.fireParticles($(this));
        toggleNav();

    $this.css({
        backgroundColor: '#78e08f',
        transition: ".25s all"
    });



$.ajax({
url: "/verify_user_selected_answer",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: {user_id: current_user, question: question_id, answer: current_answer.text()},
success: function(response){
$("#display_result").text(response["result"]);
}
});
});
});
```

I get errors such as unexpected end of input, or an issue about the parentheses. But the code itself doesn't run when its combined

here's my HTML:

```
  <% mcq.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <div class="gr-question--choice">
      <%= link_to answer, "javascript:void(0);", class: "answer" %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

Comment: How did you "combine" them? Can you show us the code? When you say it doesn't work, can you be more specific? Is there an error in your browser JS console you get?

Comment: Also, just one thing that catches my eye, "current_user" is a param you are passing in. Are you using that as some sort of security? I ask, because that's a real bad idea. Anyone could pass in whatever user_id they wanted to create responses for any user. I would think you'd want to keep your current_user in session as they are answering things. Just asking in case you have a security problem that's gone  overlooked

Comment: @NathanKontny I updated my post. I'm so thankful that you brought up the current_user bit, I was looking for a way to track users progress, so that was the way I got it working. I guess someone could spoof the user id in the source before clicking on submit.. i don't see any other way to pass the user id in, though with ruby/rails.

Comment: I added an answer below to the original question. As for current_user... do you have people login? If you do, then Rails can store that current_user id in the session of your application. https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/ This is what sessions are for: saving data across requests. Any reason a session with current_user_id won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly tabbing this code out is really going to help you spot problems. For example, here's your code you pasted above but I've simply just indented things properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.answer").on( "click", function( event ) {
        var current_answer = $(this);
        var question_id = '<%= mcq.id %>';
        var current_user = "<%= current_user.id %>";

        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text() === $(".correct-choice").text()) {

            clickSpark.setParticleImagePath('../../correct-answer-checkmark.png');
            clickSpark.setParticleCount(50);
            clickSpark.setParticleSize(20);
            clickSpark.setParticleSpeed(12);
            clickSpark.fireParticles($(this));
            toggleNav();

            $this.css({
                backgroundColor: '#78e08f',
                transition: ".25s all"
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/verify_user_selected_answer",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {user_id: current_user, question: question_id, answer: current_answer.text()},
                success: function(response){
                    $("#display_result").text(response["result"]);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Now you can spot a couple problems. For example, there's no closing bracket or closing parenthesis to `$(document).ready(function() {` or else you'd see them nicely align. Also if you just follow your eye down the indentations, you'll see that the if statement ends with a bracket and parenthesis. Here, I'll add some comments where I mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.answer").on( "click", function( event ) {
        var current_answer = $(this);
        var question_id = '<%= mcq.id %>';
        var current_user = "<%= current_user.id %>";

        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text() === $(".correct-choice").text()) {

            clickSpark.setParticleImagePath('../../correct-answer-checkmark.png');
            clickSpark.setParticleCount(50);
            clickSpark.setParticleSize(20);
            clickSpark.setParticleSpeed(12);
            clickSpark.fireParticles($(this));
            toggleNav();

            $this.css({
                backgroundColor: '#78e08f',
                transition: ".25s all"
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/verify_user_selected_answer",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {user_id: current_user, question: question_id, answer: current_answer.text()},
                success: function(response){
                    $("#display_result").text(response["result"]);
                }
            });
        });  //<= This isn't how you end an if block
    });

// No closing bracket + parenthesis.
```

Just fix those up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.answer").on( "click", function( event ) {
        var current_answer = $(this);
        var question_id = '<%= mcq.id %>';
        var current_user = "<%= current_user.id %>";

        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text() === $(".correct-choice").text()) {

            clickSpark.setParticleImagePath('../../correct-answer-checkmark.png');
            clickSpark.setParticleCount(50);
            clickSpark.setParticleSize(20);
            clickSpark.setParticleSpeed(12);
            clickSpark.fireParticles($(this));
            toggleNav();

            $this.css({
                backgroundColor: '#78e08f',
                transition: ".25s all"
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/verify_user_selected_answer",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {user_id: current_user, question: question_id, answer: current_answer.text()},
                success: function(response){
                    $("#display_result").text(response["result"]);
                }
            });
        }  
    });
});
```

And you should be further along. Big lesson though, use indentation as a way to see the correctness of your logic. It isn't just there for prettiness. It can really be a powerful guide.

Comment: I agree with you, and this has motivated me to start indenting my JS code. However, the fixed version you provided literally leads to nothing happening at all when I click the buttons. There are no errors in the console either? What do I do in this case?

Comment: A big thing I recommend here is start using Chrome's Breakpoints (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints). Really embrace that tool and use this as a chance to learn it. For example, you could set a breakpoint on `var current_answer = $(this);` and step through it to see what's happening. What I suspect now has changed is before you had a click handler on `$(".practice-quiz-answer-choice")` AND $("a.answer"). But now you only have one on $("a.answer"). Is an "a.answer" also a ".practice-quiz-answer-choice"? It might help to see your HTML too.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for this tool. Reminds me of ruby and rails binding.pry, which pauses the code at the line you want. I've updated my HTML, `a.answer` is a link within `.gr-question--choice`